# How to plot a function with sums?

Tags: r

I am trying to plot this equation. The only variable that changes is n. The x is always a sum from x = 1 to x = 4.

```
   x = seq(from = 1, to = 4, by = 1)
   lf = function(n) choose(4, 3)*choose(4, 1)*exp(3*n) / sum(choose(4,x)*choose(4, 4-x)*exp(x*n))
```

When I try to plot it using:

```
plot(lf, from = -3, to -3)
```

I get the error:

"longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `lf` is not *vectorized* over `n`; i.e., it doesn't accept vectors as inputs. For instance, `sum(1:x)` is also not vectorized over `x` meaning that `sum(1:(1:2))` isn't going to return `c(1, 3)`. Something similar happens with

```
sum(choose(4,x)*choose(4, 4-x)*exp(x*n))
```

in terms of `n`.

Now vectorization is needed because of the way you want to plot the function (i.e., `plot` tries to use a vector as an input). One solution would be to use

```
plot(Vectorize(lf, "n"), from = -3, to = 3)
```

Another would be to define `lf` in a vectorized manner:

```
lf <- function(n) 
  sapply(n, function(nn)
    choose(4, 3) * choose(4, 1) * exp(3 * nn) / sum(choose(4, x) * choose(4, 4 - x) * exp(x * nn)))
plot(lf, from = -3, to = 3)
```

Comment: Thank you, this was more informative than expected!

Answer (score 0):

Plot() or curve() is generating a 200 lenght vector to plot your function as n.

So when you multiply n*x the dimensions doesn't fit, and R is warning you and expanding de x array to 123412341234... and then multiply.

Put a browser in your function and you will see if it does what you really want to do.

```
lf = function(n){ 
  browser() 
  choose(4, 3)*choose(4, 1)*exp(3*n) / sum(choose(4,x)*choose(4, 4-x)**(x*n))
 }
```

Hope it helps!